# Native Query with Non Entity Class errors with unsatisfied dependency via constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class which I do not want persisted to a database.  I am simply trying to display the details via an api call using a native sql query.

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExperimentDetails {

    private String externalId;
    private String isid;
    private String name;
    private String controlledStatus;
    private String jurisdictionName;
    private String resultComments;
    private String codeName;
    private String corporateId;
}
```

My repository class:

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.pdb.testdbconn.dto.ExperimentDetails;

public interface ExperimentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ExperimentDetails, String> {

    @Query(value = "Select ce.external_id, ce.isid, ji.name, ji.controlled_status, ji.jurisdiction_name, ji.result_comments," +
    "ji.code_name, s.corporate_id " +
    "from cs_jurisdiction_information ji " +
    "Join substance s on ji.substance_id = s.id " +
    "Join controlled_event ce on ce.id = s.controlled_event_id and ce.calling_system_id = 402 and " +
    "ce.external_id = :externalId", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ExperimentDetails> getExperimentDetails(@Param("externalId") String externalId);
}
```

My Service class:

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pdb.testdbconn.dto.ExperimentDetails;
import com.pdb.testdbconn.repositories.ExperimentDetailsRepository;

@Service
public class ExperimentDetailsService {

    private ExperimentDetailsRepository experimentDetailsRepository;

    public ExperimentDetailsService(ExperimentDetailsRepository experimentDetailsRepository) {
        this.experimentDetailsRepository = experimentDetailsRepository;
    }

    public List<ExperimentDetails> getExperimentDetails(String externalId) {
        return experimentDetailsRepository.getExperimentDetails(externalId);
    }
}
```

And finally my controller:

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pdb.testdbconn.dto.ExperimentDetails;
import com.pdb.testdbconn.models.SignalsExperimentCSView;
import com.pdb.testdbconn.service.ExperimentDetailsService;
import com.pdb.testdbconn.service.SignalsExperimentCSViewService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SignalsExperimentCSViewController {
    
    private SignalsExperimentCSViewService signalsExperimentCSViewService;
    private ExperimentDetailsService experimentDetailsService;

    public SignalsExperimentCSViewController(SignalsExperimentCSViewService signalsExperimentCSViewService,
            ExperimentDetailsService experimentDetailsService) {
        this.signalsExperimentCSViewService = signalsExperimentCSViewService;
        this.experimentDetailsService = experimentDetailsService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/signals-experiments")
    public List<SignalsExperimentCSView> getSignalsExperiments() {
        return signalsExperimentCSViewService.getRecords();
    }

    @GetMapping("/signals-experiments/{externalId}")
    public List<ExperimentDetails> getSignalsExperiment(@PathVariable("externalId") String externalId){
        return experimentDetailsService.getExperimentDetails(externalId);
    }
}
```

Before I added the ExperimentDetails dto, repositories, and service I was able to spin up the application and call the `getExperiments` api successfully. However, after adding these classes I am getting the following error:

> **Application run failed**
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'signalsExperimentCSViewController'
>
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'experimentDetailsService' defined in
> file...
>
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'experimentDetailsRepository' defined in
> com.pdb.testdbconn.repositories.ExperimentDetailsRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
> com.pdb.testdbconn.dto.ExperimentDetails at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray...

Similar errors for experimentDetailsService,

> experimentDetailsRepository not a managed type

I've read the section on projections and tried the DTO option using Lombok's `@Value`, but that did not resolve the error either.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

How can I resolve this?  While still being able to create a class that is not persisted to the database?

Comment: You need `@Entity` on `ExperimentDetails` -- this doesn't mean that all instances will be persisted to the DB, just that it can be mapped to an entity (table) in the DB. Instances will only be stored if you do it explicitly using your repository.

Comment: I tried this, and it does indeed create a table in the database, can the manipulation of the database be stopped somehow?

Comment: You may have set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create` in your properties file?

Comment: no, `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` has been the setup in the properties file

Comment: Try setting it to `validate`

Answer (score 0):

JpaRepository expects you to specify an entity that represents a table in your database and the data type of your primary key of your entity, I suggest you generate your entity and occupy that entity in the repository

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/